# JOIN with NESTED STATEMENT

Tags: sql, nested, left-join

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Financial_plan 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    advisor_ID INT NOT NULL,
    product_ID INT NOT NULL,
    price INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Advisor 
( 
    ID INT NOT NULL,  
    role_id INT NOT NULL,  
    office_id INT NOT NULL,  
    name VARCHAR (50),  
    surname VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,  
    active NUMERIC (1) NOT NULL,  

    PRIMARY KEY (ID)  
);
```

And I do a new column count_plan like this

```
SELECT 
    Advisor_ID, count_plan 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         Financial_plan.Advisor_ID, 
         COUNT(Financial_plan.ID) AS count_plan
     FROM 
         Financial_plan
     GROUP BY 
         Financial_plan.Advisor_ID
     ORDER BY 
         count_plan DESC)
```

I would like to JOIN a new table with column count_plan with Advisor table, but can't figure it out

I try

```
SELECT 
    Advisor_ID, 
    count_plan 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         Financial_plan.Advisor_ID, 
         COUNT(Financial_plan.ID) AS count_plan
     FROM 
         Financial_plan
     GROUP BY 
         Financial_plan.Advisor_ID
     ORDER BY 
         count_plan DESC) Advisor_plan
LEFT JOIN 
    Advisor ON Advisor_plan.Advisor_ID = Advisor.ID
```

This statement doesnt do the join.

I would like to add to information from Advisor table to record of the best advisors by number of plans.

So I would like to get table like this

```
Advisor_ID count_plan role_id office_id name surname active
```

Comment: Clarify *doesn't work* - do you get an error? If so: **what** error? Do you get no results? Wrong results? What would be the correct results?

Comment: what doesn't work exactly?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As every advisor_id is unique, you have a 1:! relation to advisor, so you need to add only the missing columns

> ```
> SELECT 
>     Advisor_ID, 
>     count_plan,
>     role_id,
>     office_id,
>     name,
>     surname,
>     active
> FROM 
>     (SELECT 
>          Financial_plan.Advisor_ID, 
>          COUNT(Financial_plan.ID) AS count_plan
>      FROM 
>          Financial_plan
>      GROUP BY 
>          Financial_plan.Advisor_ID
>      ORDER BY 
>          count_plan DESC) Advisor_plan
> LEFT JOIN 
>     Advisor ON Advisor_plan.Advisor_ID = Advisor.ID
> ```
>
> ```
> Advisor_ID | count_plan | role_id | office_id | name | surname | active
> ---------: | ---------: | ------: | --------: | :--- | :------ | -----:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5fc2889f68226a7854ba0f47ec72e9c4)*